# Refactoring minimum method

Tags: java

I am working on pathfind where I have need to get minimum of vararg integers where I can get one or more integers.
I was created method which returns minimum, but my Leed Developer said that this is not good enough, and that I have to do some refactoring and improve this method.Here is my code:

```
public int getMinimalValue(int... arguments) {
    if(arguments.length == 0)
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Method is called without arguments.");
    int localMinimum = arguments[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++)
        if (arguments[i] < localMinimum)
            localMinimum = arguments[i];
    return localMinimum;
}
```

I don't know why this method is not good enough when it returns minimum always. I am trying to find another solution, but I'm stuck. Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: That code doesn't compile, please fix it and indent it

Comment: @Senko  Can you please edit your code and add the proper indentation?

Comment: Your code looks OK. What was his criticism exactly?

Comment: @Bohemian: I do not know. He was very undetermined. He said that this method have to be improved.

Comment: @SenkoValjkovic: that's pretty crappy "advise" he gave you then. You should ask for clarification.

Comment: This question is better to be asked on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your lead developer is right. Your solution is not good enough.
Try this:

```
public int getMinimalValue(int firstArg, int... remainingArgs) {
        int minimum = firstArg;
        for (int arg : remainingArgs) {
            if (arg < minimum) {
                minimum = arg;
            }
        }
        return minimum;
    }
```

Your solution have big problem! You didn't note that when this method will be used with no arguments that you will get exception instead of the minimum. 
If you perform unit tests against this method, tests will fail.

With this solution you have several benefits:

- Method which pass the JUnit tests and always return minimum instead throwing IllegalArgumentException (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Method is called without arguments. - from your code)
- You can use foreach loop
- Easy for maintance
- Code looks nice

Comment: How is this more efficient than his solution? Can you elaborate on that? All you do is change from a normal `for` to an enhanced one. Which will make very little difference in terms of performance as far as I know.

Comment: Responding to your edits: why would his code not be testable? You explicitly **dropped** the validation AND you **changed** the method signature. That is not acceptable at all. Your solution would require the input to be manually separated for no reason. I would consider this a worse solution, even considering the fact that the method implementation itself is more readable.

Comment: -1 You don't know that an exception is not desirable. Also, this code can't be used to pass an `int[]`. You have also changed the signature, which may not be acceptable - for example this method may be part of an interface. Finally, your code is not more efficient.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - His method will not return minimal value if it usew with no args. Is this situation will produce test fail? Second, I read his story and regarding of this I saw that he need at least one argument.

Comment: @BoskoMijin: his method will throw an exception, as it probably should. How would you determine a minimum value if you have no arguments to determine it from? Tests can expect an exception to be thrown.

Comment: His implementation is written such that it demands at least one value - personally I do think this version is cleaner and more testable

Comment: Why would it ever be acceptable to have to write `GetMinimum(x, new int[] { y, z, w })`? You want to get the minimum of an array, forcing the user to split it up is bad design. Why would this be more testable?

Comment: The original works with either an array of ints or a list of int scalars.  This version doesn't. While I agree that your code is readable, it doesn't perform the same operation the original did.

Comment: Senko was clear enough - this method always returns a minimum. It is not correct. This method return minimum only if it used with passed one or more arguments.

Comment: @BoskoMijin: I believe he meant that he can input one or more integers. Not that he should always return one integer. He explicitly throws an exception to prevent 0 integers being given.

Comment: Bosko is right. There can be passed zero to more arguments. Because of that I wrote this throw. Bosko's solution works for me. Thanks.

Comment: what would you do then, if there are passed 0 arguments? What will be your minimum? This solution won't even allow you to do that. It requires 1 (the first argument).

Comment: I am glad this helped. @Jeroen Vannevel - Your observations led me to a deeper analysis. Much thanks. And - Yes this solution requires at least one argument.

Comment: @boris it's not the same - you couldn't pass a `int[]`

Comment: @Bohemian This method can be used without any argument - getMinimalValue(); There will no errors in compile time, but in runtime there is exception instead of minimal int, what Senko don't expect.